# How to delete an already pushed change set in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have pushed two change sets on Mercurial and I wanted to delete them. I have checked [How to remove changesets from a Mercurial repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520697/how-to-remove-changesets-from-a-mercurial-repository) 
but it seems it works with committed change sets only.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Dealing with an already-pushed changeset is specifically noted in this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520926/3195477

Answer (score 0):

There is no ultimate answer to your question - and the answer may well be "there is no way".

The main questions are: 
* Do you AND the remote repository use changeset evolution / are the commits still in draft phase?

If so: excellent. Just create and push updated commits which replace / obsolete the commits.

If not: Do you have access to that (remote) repository and can work on that?

Wonderful. Login to the remote machine (or the administrative web panel) and remove the unwanted changesets, e.g. be uncommit or rollback (only the last commit, not recommended).

If not: you have a problem. Contact the admin and ask them for that access. Maybe enable changeset evolution and remove with its tooling the questionable commits.

Also make sure you remove the exact same thing in your local repository.

As last resort: Use `hg backout`. That will not remove the commit. But will undo it by basically committing the reverse.